# Python - Tkinter -Sqlite - existe manera de saber si el combobox seleccionado es igual a otro para meterlo en distintas base de datos

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

gente que tal , tengo un tema , yo tengo la ventana de cargar productos en base de datos  , la cuestion es que quiero hacer categorias de productos, entonces a la hora de cargar un nuevo producto tengo un combobox con las distintas opciones, mi pregunta es como puedo hacer para que si la opcion seleccionada es igual a la tabla bebidas que me guarde el producto en la tabla de sqlite BEBIDAS nose si se entiende , aca dejo el codigo del combo box

```
    # Input Precio Venta - frame1 
        Label(frame1, text="Categoria: ", font=("arial 10 bold"), bg="#83D6A8").grid(row=10,column=0,sticky=W+E, pady=2)
        self.combo = ttk.Combobox(frame1, state="readonly", width=18, font=("arial 15"), justify=CENTER)
        self.combo["values"] = ["Bebidas", "Bebidas Alcoholicas", "Golosinas", "Comestibles", "Cigarrillos", "Otros"]
        self.combo.grid(row = 11, column = 0, pady=2)
```

````
def insertar_producto(self):
        # Insertar Producto boton ventana agregar / quitar Producto

        if len(self.descripcion.get()) != 0 and len(self.stock.get()) != 0 and len(self.precio_costo.get()) != 0 and len(self.precio_venta.get()) != 0:
            consult = 'INSERT INTO Productos VALUES(NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)'
            parametros = (self.descripcion.get(), self.stock.get(), self.precio_costo.get(), self.precio_venta.get(), self.combo.get(), )
            self.ejecuta_consulta(consult, parametros)
            self.mensaje['text'] = 'Producto {} agregado correctamente'.format(self.descripcion.get())
            self.descripcion.delete(0, END)
            self.stock.delete(0, END)
            self.precio_costo.delete(0, END)
            self.precio_venta.delete(0, END)
            self.combo.set("")
        else:
            self.mensaje['text'] = 'Todos los campos son requeridos'
        self.obtener_producto() ```
````

Comment: ¿La idea sería entonces tener una tabla por cada categoría del ComboBox (6 en tu ejemplo)? Aparentemente, ahora mismo tienes una tabla Productos donde lo agregas todo, ten en cuenta que podrías usar una sola tabla y agregar una columna categoría. Otra opción es relacionar tablas vía foreign key con Productos como padre y relaciones one-to-many.

Comment: claro en la treeview de productos tengo categoria, el tema es que me gustaria hacer otra ventana para mostrar por ejemplo en bebidas y que me salga todos los productos que estan cargados en bebidas .

aunque suena algo redundante , pero si lo dejo todo en una misma tabla , no voy a poder mostrar un resumen de los productos que estan cargados en distintas categorias